# How to enable master and slave in Laravel Framework 6.0?

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, laravel-6, master-slave

I'm having one master and two slave database servers(Replication of Master). If the master fails it automatically Change the Read and Write requests to the next available slave.

I want to write data to 192.168.1.1 (read host) if the write-host fails (196.168.1.2)

How to Configure this in Laravel 6.0?

I had tried this.

```
'mysql' => [
    'read' => [
        'host' => '192.168.1.1',
    ],
    'write' => [
        'host' => '196.168.1.2'
    ],
    'sticky'    => true,
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'database'  => 'database',
    'username'  => 'root',
    'password'  => '',
    'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
    'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
],
```

Answer (score 0):

Add additional hosts:

```php
'mysql' => [
    'read' => [
        'host' => [
            '192.168.1.1',
            '192.168.1.10',     // <-- more slaves
            '192.168.1.11',     // <-- more slaves
    ],
    'write' => [
        'host' => '196.168.1.2'
    ],
    'sticky'    => true,
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'database'  => 'database',
    'username'  => 'root',
    'password'  => '',
    'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
    'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
],
```

[Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/database#read-and-write-connections)

Comment: I want to write data to 192.168.1.1 (read host) if the write-host fails (196.168.1.2)

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65811976/edit) your original question to include that information.